# How is Edward Dalton still standing, even after being bitten by a vampire?

Tags: plot-explanation, daybreakers

In the movie [Daybreakers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daybreakers), there is a scene where Charles Bromley is turning into human by biting Edward Dalton on his neck. Why didn't Edward suffer after the bite?

[image]

How is he still standing, even after being bitten on the neck by a vampire?

Comment: I thought Dalton has gained immunity to vampiric infection by now.